# Cauchy–Schwarz type Inequality $(x+2y+3z+4t)(x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2) \geqslant \frac{35-\sqrt{10}}{54}(x+y+z+t)^3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> For $x,y,z,t \geqslant 0$, prove that
> $$ \tag{1} (x+2y+3z+4t)(x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2) \geqslant \frac{35-\sqrt{10}}{54}(x+y+z+t)^3.$$

**Observations**

1. This inequality is not symmetric nor cyclic. We cannot order the variables.
2. This has 4 variables. My first attempt is to assume that $x+y+z+t=1$, then plug in $t=1-x-y-z$ to $(1)$ and try to reduce number of variables. But there are so many cases to consider.
3. I think Cauchy–Schwarz is a good one. I just don't know how to get the cosntant $\frac{35-\sqrt{10}}{54}$ .

Comment: Under the assumption $x+y+z+t=1,$the given inequality reduces to $$(1+y+2z+3t)(1-2x(1-x)-2(yz+zt+ty))\ge\dfrac{35-\sqrt{10}}{54}.$$ Now consider the function $$f(x)=2(1+y+2z+3t)\left(x^2-x+\left(\dfrac12-(yz+zt+ty)\right)\right)\,\,\,\,\,\forall x\in[0,1].$$  
Minimum of the quadratic function is $f_{\min}\left(\dfrac12\right)=(1+y+2z+3t)\left(-1+(1-2(yz+zt+ty))\right).$  
Now consider this minimum as a quadratic function of $y$ on the domain $[0,\frac12].$ And so on. I hope this lengthy argument will leads you to the given lower bound.

Comment: @Bumblebee I think your argument does not work. We can see this from several aspects. (1) when $x + y + z + t = 1$, the optimal $(x, y, z, t)$ is $x = 1/2-(1/20)\sqrt{10}, y= 1/3-(1/60)\sqrt{10}, z = 1/6+(1/60)\sqrt{10}, t = (1/20)\sqrt{10}$. $x$ is not equal to $1/2$. (2) Although your form $2(1+y+2z+3t)\left(x^2-x+\left(\dfrac12-(yz+zt+ty)\right)\right)$ is correct, however, $x$ is not independent of $y, z, t$, so you can not minimize $x^2 - x$ by $x = 1/2$.

Answer (score 7):

This is a typical problem that can be solved by brute force with homogeneization techniques and Lagrange multipliers. Since the inequality is homogeneous, it is not restrictive to assume $x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2=1$, then compute
$$ \max_{x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2=1} f(x,y,z,t)=\max_{x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2=1}\frac{x+2y+3z+4t}{(x+y+z+t)^3} $$
by imposing $2x = \lambda\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and so on. Lagrange equations then give that the stationary points are eigenvectors for the rank-$2$ matrix
$$ M=\begin{pmatrix}2&5&8&11\\ 1&4&7&10 \\ 0&3&6&9 \\ -1&2&5&8 \end{pmatrix}$$
that has a unique eigenvector with positive coordinates. It follows that the maximum is achieved at
$$ (x,y,z,t) = \mu\left(\sqrt{10}-1,\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{10}-\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{10}+\frac{1}{3},1\right) $$
and $\mu$ can be computed by imposing that $x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2=1$. That also proves
$$\max_{x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2=1} f(x,y,z,t)=\frac{35-\sqrt{10}}{54}$$
as wanted.

Answer (score 0):

*Remark*: Here is a proof without using calculus. Sometimes, while we used calculus to motivate our solution, we do not need to include any calculus in the solution!

**Proof**.

Since the desired inequality is homogeneous,
assume that $t = 1$. The desired inequality becomes
$$(x+2y+3z+4)(x^2+y^2+z^2+1) \geqslant \frac{35-\sqrt{10}}{54}(x+y+z+1)^3. \tag{1}$$

Let
$$a := x + y + z, \quad b := y + 2z.$$

We use the following identity
$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = \frac16(5a^2 - 6 ab + 3b^2) + 
\frac16 (x - 2y + z)^2. \tag{2}$$

From (1) and (2), it suffices to prove that, for all $a, b \ge 0$,
$$(a + b + 4) \left[\frac16(5a^2 - 6 ab + 3b^2) + 1\right] \ge \frac{35-\sqrt{10}}{54}(a + 1)^3.\tag{3}$$

Let
$$Q := \frac{27 + 2\sqrt{10}}{39}, \quad C := \frac{35-\sqrt{10}}{54}.$$

We have
\begin{align*}
 \mathrm{LHS}_{(3)} - \mathrm{RHS}_{(3)}
 &= \frac12 b(b - Qa)^2 + p_1 b^2 +  p_2 b + p_3 
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
 p_1 &= Qa - a /2 + 2, \\
 p_2 &= -a^2/6 - 4a + 1 - Q^2a^2/2, \\
 p_3 &= 5a^3/6 + 4 + 10a^2/3 + a - C(a+1)^3.
\end{align*}

Clearly, $p_1 > 0$. It suffices to prove that
$$4p_1 p_3 - p_2^2 \ge 0$$
or
\begin{align*}
 &\frac{(51931\sqrt {10} -18774
  ) {a}^{2} + ( 264667\sqrt {10}+514189) a+166296
  \sqrt{10} + 1618851}{2313441}\\[10pt]
 &\times (2\sqrt{10} - 1 - a)^{2}\ge 0
\end{align*}
which is true.

We are done.