Prove $( x + 2y + 3z)( x^2 + y^2 + z^2) \geq \frac{20 - 2\sqrt{2}}{27} ( x + y + z )^3 $

Let $(x,y,z)$ be non negative real numbers . Prove that  $$\left( x + 2y + 3z \right)\left( x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \right) \geq \frac{20 - 2\sqrt{2}}{27} \left( x + y + z \right)^3. $$

My Attempt
We are given the inequality:
$(x + 2y + 3z)(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) \geq \frac{20 - 2\sqrt{2}}{27}(x + y + z)^3$
where  $x, y, z \geq 0$ .
First I analyzed the inequality for  $z \geq x$
Initially, I observed that if  $z \geq x$ , we can establish:
LHS = $(x + 2y + 3z)(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) \geq 2(x + y + z)(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)$.
Next, applying the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, I deduce:
$(x + y + z)^2 \leq 3(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)$.
From this, I multiply both sides by  $x + y + z$ , leading to:
$2(x + y + z)(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) \geq \frac{2}{3}(x + y + z)^3$.
So far, this confirms that for  $z \geq x$ , the left-hand side is greater than or equal to the right-hand side. Therefore, the inequality holds in this case
Next I Considered the case  $z < x$
Now, I assume  $z < x$ . Without loss of generality, let’s normalize the condition by assuming  $x + y + z = 3$ , which simplifies the expression a bit.
Define  $a = x - 1$ ,  $b = y - 1$ , and $c = z - 1$ , which implies $a + b + c = 0$  and thus  $-1 \leq a, b, c \leq 2$ .
Substituting into the original inequality, the left-hand side becomes:
$(6 + c - a)(2a^2 + 2ac + 2c^2 + 3)$,
and the right-hand side becomes:
$20 - 2\sqrt{2}$.
At this point, I substituted the expressions for $u = a - c$  and $v = a + c$  to simplify the equation further. This transformed the inequality into a quadratic expression in terms of ( u ) and  $v$ , but after trying multiple algebraic manipulations, I encountered difficulty simplifying it into a form where I could clearly prove the inequality holds.
At this stage, I’m unsure how to proceed further. Could someone kindly guide me on how to handle the expressions and move forward from here?

Here is a similar question with four variables: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1445853/42969. See also https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h586072p3466880 on AoPS. (Both found with Approach0)

Remark. This is directly from my previous answer for this question. I motivated my solution by computer, although the solution itself is verifiable by hand.
Let
$$a := x + y + z, \quad b := y + 2z.$$
We use the following identity
$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = \frac16(5a^2 - 6 ab + 3b^2) + 
\frac16 (x - 2y + z)^2. \tag{1}$$
It suffices to prove that, for all $a, b \ge 0$,
$$(a + b) \cdot \frac16(5a^2 - 6 ab + 3b^2) \ge \frac{20-2\sqrt{2}}{27}a^3,$$
or
$$\frac{5 + 4\sqrt{2}}{378}(6b\sqrt{2} + 7a + 3b)(3b\sqrt{2} - a - 3b)^2 \ge 0$$
which is true.
We are done.

My suggestion for this kind of problems is to consider two independent vectors $a,b$ of $R^n$ with positive components and two positive numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$. We want to  minimize
$$x\mapsto \frac{(\langle x,a \rangle) ^{\alpha}}{(\langle x,b \rangle) ^{\beta}}\times \|x\|^{\beta-\alpha}$$
(Example $n=3,\ \alpha=1,\ \beta=3, \ a=(1,2,3),\ b=(1,1,1)).$ Computing the gradient shows that it is zero for some $x_0=Aa+Bb$. Since this is a half line we look for $r$ such that $A=rB$ and loo, $r$ satisfies a nice second degree equation whose roots give max and min.
